# comparing correlations with range restrictions

Tags: correlation

I have ability test results on several tests.
I would like to compare the correlation between these tests on different ability levels - eg. my hypothesis is that I will find higher correlations at lower ability levels than at high ability levels.
Can I simply take people who score lower than eg. -1Z on both test and people who score higher than +1Z on both test and compare these correlations?

I am thinking something along the following lines - using R to demonstrate:

```
library(mirt)
data <- key2binary(SAT12, key = c(1,4,5,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,4,2,1,5,3,4,4,1,4,3,3,4,1,3,5,1,3,1,5,4,5))
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$rS<-rowSums(data)
data$zS<-scale(data$rS)[,1]

dH<-subset(data,data$zS>0.5)
cH<-cor(dH$Item.1,dH$Item.2)

dL<-subset(data,data$zS< -0.5)
cL<-cor(dL$Item.1,dL$Item.2)

require(cocor) # load package
cocor.indep.groups(
  r1.jk=cH,
  r2.hm=cL,
  n1=nrow(dH),
  n2=nrow(dL),
  alternative="two.sided", alpha=0.05, conf.level=0.95, null.value=0
)
```

Here is an image of my actual data - created by the localgauss package - suggesting that there is a difference in the association between the two variables at high and low values. Unfortunately I am still unable to get a metric of this difference.

[image]

Comment: Trying this will show that it is not a good idea. (I take it that e.g. $-1Z$ is eccentric notation for standard score $z = -1$.)

Comment: I have updated my question with an example (using z=+-0.5). Could you let me know what is the problem with this approach and how to do it properly? Thx.

Comment: It's good practice here not to assume that people all use any particular software and to state any software you use in an example. The problems with your approach include (a) any cut-off is utterly arbitrary; (b) correlations for any particular quadrant are almost inevitably closer to zero and you would need to separate out that effect from any genuine phenomenon. In my view the approach is fundamentally flawed, so there is no way to do it properly.

Comment: I have now updated the question stating that I used R for the example.
I believe that the correlation between different measures of ability in my data decreases as scores on these measures increase. If my method to answer this question is fundamentally flawed, what would be the correct method to answer this?

Comment: Sorry, I won't be seeming constructive, but I see no reason even to think about correlations for subsets of $(x, y)$ except those defined by other variables. But you may be reaching for something like http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176349156

Comment: I looked at the article and it seems very relevant but way too high for me. I looked at the localgauss package that seems to be doing something like what I need. It produces a nice graph (updated my question), but unfortunately no metric.

Comment: How many values is each correlation based on? I know it varies, but minimum, median, maximum?

Comment: The whole dataset contains around 10 000 observations. Ultimately I could just put them in 4 correlations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the localgauss R package I could get local correlations.
I could generate confidence intervals and compare these correlations using bootstrap.